# Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider when calling image from URI in RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, image, uri, android-permissions, permission-denied

I am trying to load an image from URI and my code works in a activity but when I tried to load the image from an `RecyclerView.Adapter` in `onBindViewHolder` it shows me this error. And also am calling this adapter from a `Fragment`.

Edit:

The path of URI is an image which user picks from the device and when I have tried to load the image from different `Activity` not related to `Activity` from which image has been picked and my code works perfectly fine.

Error

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{e8f7e7f 20114:my.package.name/u0a290} (pid=20114, uid=10290) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
```

The code am using to load the image

```
user_image = findViewById(R.id.user_image);
String path = sharedPreferences.getString("imagePath", "default");
if (path.equals("default")) {
    user_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.profile);
} else {
    user_image.setImageURI(Uri.parse(path));
}
```

The code for image picking and saving it's path

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setType("image/*");
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Select Picture"), IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

`OnActivityResult`

```
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = requireActivity().getSharedPreferences("USERDATA", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

if (selectedImageUri != null) {
    image_view.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
    imagePath = selectedImageUri.toString();
    editor.putString("imagePath", imagePath);
    editor.apply();
 }
```

Comment: Did you use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT to obtain that uri is the message.

Comment: It works in the activity where you got the uri and only in the moment that you got the uri. You can try as well to use the uri the next day in that activity to see that it fails.

Comment: @blackapps I have added more details

Comment: `Did you use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT to obtain that uri is the message.`

Comment: @blackapps even after using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` it still shows me the same error

Comment: Yes as that is not enough. You should also take persistable uri permission in order to use the uri later or in a different activity.